# Can I install Oracle on the portable xp which is installed on my WD 160gb USB Hard drive?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, portability

Please help me.

I want to install a address printing software. Instead of using Internal Hard Drive, I wanted to use USB Hard drive to give me flexibility and convinence to have the system portable.

I want to know, if I can successfully install Portable XP on my USB Hard drive. If yes, can I install oracle on my hard drive which operates Portable XP? Software is made on Oracle?

How can I install it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find much help about that question in this forum.

This is taking from the FAQ:

**Frequently Asked Questions**
What kind of questions can I ask here?
Programming questions, of course!

Sorry ;-)